# Cannot dynamically change PageMod ContentScriptOptions since Firefox 30

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

The code below was working up to Firefox 30. Now, I cannot change the options attached to my pageMod by calling the function `newOptions()`.

Is this a known bug? Any suggestions to make it work with Firefox >= 30?

```js
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');

exports.main = function(type) {

    var mod = pageMod.PageMod({
        include: ['http://example.com/*'],
        contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
        attachTo: ['existing', 'top'],
        contentScriptFile: data.url('js/file.js'),
        contentScriptOptions: {
                options: ...
        },
        onAttach: function(opt) {

            // Save user preferences
            opt.port.on('save', function(o) {
                newOptions(); // This works OK
            });
        }
    });

    function newOptions(){

        // change the contentScriptOptions [This does not work anymore]
        mod.contentScriptOptions = {
             options:...
        };

        // cause the page-mod to re-evaluate
       require("tabs").activeTab.reload();

    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please log a bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK&component=General

Comment: @canuckistani, done it a few hours ago. See my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027605:

> Changing contentScriptOptions after the PageMod instance is created is
>   an unsupported, undocumented feature. the fact that it ever worked was
>   probably some side-effect of an implementation detail, that we
>   apparently changed between fx29 and 30.
>
> if your preferences can change during the running of your addon, you
>   should switch to keeping them in a global variable and using messages
>   to send that data to the content script.
>
> in other words, this is most likely a WONTFIX.